# Doctrine2 generates two extra tables for a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

## Problem

I'm setting up a database by using Symfony2 and Doctrine2 (annotation). I followed the examples perfectly ([Doctrine2 relationship documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)), but somehow when I update my schema (`doctrine:schema:update --force`) it creates two additional tables.

My two entities are Article and District, the code is below.

## Code

### Article entity:

```
/**
 *
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $districts
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="District", inversedBy="articles")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="articles_districts",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="district_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $districts;
```

### District entity:

```
/**
 *
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $articles
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="districts")
 */
protected $articles;
```

## Question

The two extra tables that are being created are: `articles_districts` (the one I specified in the JoinTable section) and `article_district` (the other one that somehow gets created automatically).

The `articles_districts` table works as expected and ID's are inserted when a new entry is made. The `article_district` remains empty, and thus, is pretty useless. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your district entity should use the mappedBy annotation:

```
/**
 *
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $articles
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="districts")
 */
protected $articles;
```

At the moment you are trying to have two owning sides to your entity relationship: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: Thank you very much Luke, that did the trick! Guess I didn't follow the example perfectly after all :)

Comment: Its an easy one to miss! Can you accept the answer please so people looking know its correct :)

Comment: I'll accept the answer as soon as I can, you answered too fast so I couldn't mark it as such straight away!